# ajax not reaching php side

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get rid of my html form submits and replace them by Ajax ( X M L H t p Request). I have set the form return value to "false" and I have written a small test to test the Ajax mechanism.
At the Java script side I do receive the ready state 4 and status 200, so sending data succeeds apparently, but at the PHP side the variables never arrive.

I try to pick them up the usual way with the POST method, the same way like I did before when receiving html submits, of which the simplified form is:

$x = $_POST['x'];
echo $x;

'x' having been sent with Ajax, state 4 , status 200.

Can anyone tell what am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the entire AJAX code, otherwise it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you are posting JSON data?  Try this snippet:

```
switch ($httpMethod) {
          case 'POST':
          $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $jsonData = json_decode($rest_json,true);
            foreach($jsonData as $item){
                var_dump($item);
                $studentsCollection->insert($item);
            }
            $response = $studentsCollection->find();
            break;
```

This is from a simple rest api I was using.  Just change it to suit yourself without a verb switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your ajax request is being submitted via GET instead of POST. Try $_GET instead of $_POST, or use $_REQUEST to cover both your bases. If you're not using jQuery, I'd recommend using it, ajax is a lot easier with [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), etc.

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggent check the header of your ajax requests (in the chrome or firefox), the you can see if really your data is passing to the PHP side.

Comment: ".htaccess" could be another reason for this. There May be some rule that takes your request to some other page

Answer (score 0):

To find the issue you can use debug tool [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is good to to debug ajax request.

using Firebug you can see the ajax call.

[image]

You can see the parameters you send.

[image]

You can see the respond of the ajax request.

[image]

My suggestion is use Jquery for your javascript function.

Jquery ajax call up code -

```
           $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ServerPageUrl.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                       if(data==true)
                       {                               
                           alert("OK");
                       }
                       else
                       {    
                           alert("Error save data");
                       }


                    }
                });
```

You can learn more about jquery ajax from [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[More help full page](http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Thanks.